# Issue for increase the date choices for datepicker in f.input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I want to open the range of dates in my  date picker. It's plugged in a form input <%= f.input :birthday_date>.
From now it's possible for users to choose between 2014 -> 2024 I want user could pick a date between 2005 and Time.now.year ?

[image]

Comment: I found it <%= f.input :birthday_date, as: :date, start_year: 2005, end_year: Date.today.year, label:"Date de naissance" %>

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `date_select` and specify the `:start_year` and `:end_year`:

```
<%= f.date_select :birthday_date, start_year: Date.new(2005, 01, 01).year, end_year: Date.today.year %>
```

See: [date_select()](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select)